# How to generate the Nakagami-m fading channel in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, channel, fading

I have successfully measured BER performance on the Rayleigh channel, but not on Nakagami fading. Because I haven't found a way to generate the Nakagami-m fading channel model.

Rayleigh channels can be created easily using Matlab code.

```
Rayleigh_channel = (randn(1,1)+1i*randn(1,1))/sqrt(2)
```

How can I generate the Nakagami-m fading channel?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to [edit] your question to contain more details, such as what a Nakagami-m fading channel is. I for one have no idea, and going on a treasure hunt around the web for it is not my cup of tea. Please help us help you by elaborating a bit on what a Rayleigh channel is, what BER stands for, and what formula should be used for Nakagami-m fading.